# Conversao para float ... problema

Tags: php

Estou tentando converter o valor string ''1234,56'' em `float`, porém achei essa forma de converter número mas vem somente em inteiro. De qual forma eu consigo trazer os valores em float ?

Resultado fica assim : `float` 1234

Mas preciso dos valores após a virgula tb...

```html
$val_orcamento = $this->request->post['valorca'];
    $quantidade = $this->request->post['quantidade'];
    $valor_unit = $this->request->post['valor'];
    
    $varquantidade[0] = ((float)$quantidade[0]*1.00);
    $varunit[0] = ((float)$valor_unit[0]*1.00);
```

Answer (score 3):

O principal problema é: PHP trata valor float utilizando o '.', não ','. Ou seja, se você pede pro PHP converter "1234,56" em float, ele vai ler até o "1234", encontrar uma virgula e ignorar aquilo". Para converter um número com virgula em float, trate da seguinte forma:

```
$number = "12345,67";
$float = (float) str_replace(',', '.', $number);
```

Prontinho. Só isso já resolve o problema do seu número não ser tratado corretamente como float, pois, para o PHP ele realmente não é um float! =)

Comment: Muito obrigado viu , deu certo aqui hehe , fiquei tão envolvido no codigo que esqueci que PHP lê somente ponto :)